# I am failing to encode a list of objects into JSON format using flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of objects in the following format below

```
var data = [
  {name: 'Name', type: 'STRING', mode: 'REQUIRED'},
  {name: 'Age', type: 'INTEGER'},
  {name: 'Weight', type: 'FLOAT'},
  {name: 'IsMagic', type: 'BOOLEAN'},
];
```

this was how i created the object below

```
List<dynamic> data = [];


class dataObject {
  String name;
  String type;

  dataObject({required this.name, required this.type});
}
```

i am trying to encode it into JSON format in order to send it over the internet, this was my attempt below but i keep getting the error

```
Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'dataObject'
```

this was my attempt

```
Future creatingTable() async {
    var url = Uri.parse(
        'https://us-central1-denance-cbf3f.cloudfunctions.net/api/create_table');
    var response =
        await http.post(
            url,
            body: jsonEncode(data.toJson()),
            headers: < String, String > {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
        );
    print(
        'Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
    print(
        'Response body: ${response.body}');
}
```

I'm not sure how where i am going wrong but would appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: how did you implement your toJson() function? can you please show it to us?

Answer (score 0):

JSON object in dart is just a Map<String, dynamic> object.
You don't need to call jsonDecode if you already have a toJson function
in your class dataObject. Just make it return a Map object like this:

```
class dataObject {
  String name;
  String type;

  dataObject({required this.name, required this.type});

  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String,dynamic> json = {};
      
    json['name'] = name;
    json['type'] = type;
    
    return json;
  }
}

...

var response =
  await http.post(
    url,
    body: dataObjectInstance.toJson(),
    headers: < String, String > {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  );
```

Comment: i tried it and now it says The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the type 'List'.